# What happen to PubSub messages when not consumed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

According to the [Cloud PubSub documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas?hl=en) messages cease to be stored if not consumed within 7 days.

> Retains unacknowledged messages in persistent storage for 7 days from the moment of publication.

- What happens to PubSub messages when the retention delay is over ? Are they simply deleted ?
- Is there a log entry generated for a lost message ?
- Is there a way to know how many messages were lost ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the seven-day retention expires, the messages are deleted. No long entry is generated for these deletions. There is not a metric to determine how many messages are deleted, though you could set up [alerting](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/) on the [`subscription/oldest_unacked_message_age` metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub) in Stackdriver to know when you have messages that are close to the seven-day retention limit.